# MVC Slow Partial View Rendering after Ajax call with IE only

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

Are there any known issues with Internet Explorer and the speed of partial page rendering after an AJAX call? I have a div in my *LAYOUT* view as such:

```
<div id="customersearch">
    @Html.Action("Customers")
</div>
```

It doesn't load anything at first (on the GET). In my Index view I have an actual text box where you can search for customers, so when the document is ready, the jquery does this:

```
    $(function () {
        $('#searchbutton2').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Application/Customers',
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    searchString: $("#searchString").val()
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error searching!');
                },
                success: function (responseText) {
                    $('#customersearch').html(responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

With Chrome, iOS/Safari, FF when I search, the results come up almost instantaneously. With IE there's about a 5 second delay. I attached Visual Studio to my IIS process and set up a breakpoint to see if the actual call to the DB is what was causing an issue, but that was not it. Both were retrieving the data in a fraction of a second and the pause happens in the controller after the "return View(dbobjects)";

I've heard that this can happen with some browsers when there are tons of records being returned, but my searches literally bring up a table with ONE  and two basic fields. Yet IE is just extremely slow.

I've heard some people suggest returning JSON instead of a view, but this was always in response to issues such as this where hundreds/thousands of records were returned. Before I start going nuts with the JavaScript, does anyone see anything in this code that would cause a noticeable slowdown with IE11?

----- edited---

I changed the controller to return JSON data instead (remember it's only returning 2 fields and a single row)

```
success: function (responseText) {
                        $(".customerdetail").remove(); // clear any current results
                        //$('#customersearch').html(responseText);
                        var txt = "";
                        $.each(responseText, function (i, item) {

                            var txt = "<tr class='customerdetail'>"
                                + "<td style='text-align:center;'>" + item.ID + "</td>"
                                + "<td class='customernametd'>" + item.Name + "</td>"
                                + "</tr>";
                            $('#customertable').find('tbody').append(txt);
                        });
                    }
```

However.. there is still a 4-5 second delay from when the controller returns the JsonResult to when the SUCCESS even seems to fire in IE11. It's still super fast with other browsers

Comment: "ONE and two basic fields". And how many rows? Your code looks pretty standard, although we can't see the actual HTML in the partial view.

Comment: just two fields in a single row.  Once the success even it called, I guess it's technically not re-rendering the view, but as you can see is just replacing the "html" inside of a div inside the view with the list returned by the controller

Comment: So I changed the controller to return a JsonResult and edited the code above (at the bottom) in the jquery/ajax call. But still... a 4-5 second delay between when the controller returns the result to when the success even seems to fire.

Comment: It turns out there isn't a delay between when the controller returns the data and when the success is kicked off, but when, inside the success function, I remove existing html. It was hard to tell when the success simply had one line that did a " $('#customersearch').html(responseText);". But when I changed it to json data, I set some alerts, one when the success starts, one after the existing rows are removed, and one when it's done. The delay happens between the first two. So it's as if IE doesn't have an issue adding the data from the ajax call, but when removing existing DOM

Comment: In fact, if i change the way it removed the rows before adding new rows to an "all at once" type method such as " $('#customertable').find('tbody').empty();", it still takes about 5 seconds. How weird is that?  Actually upon first load before the ajax call, this table has a few thousands records... so.. there you go. IE doesn't seem to just dump all the contents at once

Comment: I see. That is quite odd. IE11 is a bit slower than Chrome generally to execute JS, but I've never known such a delay, especially on a very simple script like this. Does it still do this if you strip everything else out of your page and just leave this little bit? I'm wondering if it's really something else that's the problem. Also can you run on IE11 on another machine and check it's not something weird on the test PC?

Comment: I will try another machine with IE 11 (if I still can). Just FYI I *DID* try everything from .detach to simply replacing the .tbody with "".

Comment: Ultimately, I just created a pagedlist on the initial load.